Necessity of the regularity of the maps involved in Lagrange Multipliers Theorem
The Lagrange Multipliers Theorem says that if $G:\mathbb{R}^{m+n} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a $C^1$ map with regular valuer $c$, and $u:\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a $C^1$ fucntion with $p\in M:= G^{-1}(c)$ is an extrem point of the restriction $u|_M$, then $\nabla u(q)$ is orthogonal to $M$.
I understand the sharpness of the hyposthesis that $G$ is a $C^1$ map. Otherwise the regularity of $G^{-1}(c)$ as a $C^1$-manifold would not be guaranteed and one could not expect to have a well defined tangent espace at $q$. But looking at the proofs of this Theorem, I cannot understand why we couldn't ask $u$ to simply be differentiable, instead of $C^1$.

Perhaps they use the implicit function theorem and the usual hypotheses require $C^1$.

@copper.hat they do use it on G, but I don't think it's used on u
